# Creating Mask that Applies to Vectors in 3D Array

Tags: python

I could not find a previous post that specifically addressed how to create masks that work against vectors in a 3D array. I have only found previous questions and answers that either address only how masks can be applied to individual elements in a 3D array or vectors in a 2D array. So as the title states, that is exactly what I wish to do here. I want to remove all zero vectors from a 3D (x,y,z) array and the only method I can think of is to create two for loops that run over both x and (y,:) as shown in the code below. However, this does not work either because of the error message I receive when I try to run this.

```
'list' object cannot be safely interpreted as an integer
```

Moreover, even if I do get this method to work somehow, I know that using a double for loop will make this masking process very time consuming because eventually I want to apply this to array sizes in the millions. So this develops into my main question; What would be the fastest method to accomplish this?

Code:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([[[0,0,0],[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[0,0,0]],[[7,8,9],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[10,11,12]]],dtype=float)
datanonzero = np.empty([[],[]],dtype=float)
for maskclear1 in range(0,2):
    for maskclear2 in range(0,4):
        datanonzero[maskclear1,maskclear2,:] = data[~np.all(data[maskclear1,maskclear2,0:3] == 0, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   import numpy as np
   data = np.array([[[0,0,0],[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[0,0,0]],[[7,8,9],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[10,11,12]]],dtype=float)
   flatten_data = data.reshape(-1, 3)

   datanonzero = [ data[~np.all(vec == 0, axis=0)] for vec in flatten_data ]
   datanonzero = np.reshape(datanonzero, (2,-1))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what I see in the variable explorer in Spyder is a description that says "ndarray object of numpy module" for datanonzero. I am new to Python and even after Googling that term I was still not sure what that means or how to work with that kind of variable (aka, get data back from it).